# How to calculate Mean adjusted by Covariate?

Tags: mean, covariance, predictor, adjustment

I need to calculate the mean of a variable, adjusted by another variable. Both variables are ratio scaled. I found this online: https://ideas.repec.org/c/boc/bocode/s344803.html which does what I want, but only works with nominal variables.

How would I calculate the mean of a variable, adjusted by another variable?

Answer (score 2):

If you have the (x,y) pairs, you can run a regression to get a prediction equation. The predicted y-values at some relevant value of x (or multiple X's set to some relevant combination of values) would be what you are looking for in my opinion (continuous x-variables just require some relevant value(s) to be chosen).

Answer (score 2):

You could either run a linear regression and use the predicted y-values as adjusted mean - just as LSC pointed out - or you could transform your covariate from ratio scale in nominal scale by defining an arbitrary number of categories.

With the latter option, you will lose information about the covariate so you might prefer the linear regression option. However, sometimes it makes interpretation easier if the variable are on nominal scale (e.g. BMI is often sclaed as underweighted (>18), normal (18-25), overweighted (25-30) and obese (>30) - whether this is meaningful, depends on what you are going to do with the variable and how you will interpret it).

Comment: There is pretty substantial literature available that shows (in many biomedical applications at least, and many other fields) that turning a continuous covariate into a lower measurement scale (say, ordinal) is rife with problems and introduces bias and many other problems. I would avoid any artificial categories (even if they seem real, like BMI, because those are just arbitrarily defined and don't necessarily 'exist' outside of a medical chart). As LuckyPal mentioned, too, there is great information lost and a ton of inefficiency from making categories out of a continuous predictor.

Comment: In general, I agree with you. However, we should not forget that sometimes the continuous scale is only an illusion. E.g. BMI is worth basically nothing without considering muscles and body fat percentage. A difference from 22 to 23 may be completely arbitrary if you don't know whether the person with BMI of 23 lifts heavy weights or prefers the couch. But 23 vs. 28 might tell another story. Of course, I should add that the difference between 24.4 and 25.5 isn't worth anything more. You might want to treat these border cases seperately.

Comment: I’m not sure your comment really supports the idea that BMI isn’t a continuous measure. The fact that a clinician needs to use judgement to interpret the measure is irrelevant to what the actual measurement is in terms of scale. This isn’t very different from any other continuous measure used in medicine. Abnormal or even normal lab values can be inappropriately normal or appropriately abnormal—using other information to interpret this doesn’t change the true scale of the measurements. It is more often the case that a non continuous measure is made to appear continuous (likert type items).

Comment: Obscuring the actual measurement scale is none the less not appropriate, generally speaking and maybe more than in general.

Comment: As I said, from a statistical perspective I also do not recommend transformation into categorical data. But correct interpretation of less efficient method is better than wrong interpretation of efficient method, in my opinion. If OP does not now regression methods at all, it will be difficult for them to interpret it correctly. In medical research, obscuring the original measurement is done every day, and while I definitely do not appreciate that, I have to admit that sometimes it makes interpretation easier (yes, and less accurate).

Comment: the OP included a link that specifically mentions regression. In either case, the categorization is not only inefficient but more importantly can be strongly biased. So the right interpretation of the wrong number is just as useless in that case.